# Best aggregate approach regarding a query on 100k docs in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

if I have 100k docs in a collection like this:

```js
{
    {
      userName: "cary"
      time: 50
      userId: 1
    }
    {
      userName: "john"
      time: 40
      userId: 1
    }
    {
      userName: "bliss"
      time: 50
      userId: 1
    }
    {
      userName: "ross"
      time: 40
      userId: 1
    }
    ...
    ...
    etc...
}
```

I have to query in this collection such as I will get the count of users whose time is less than 40,50,60 etc

result should look like this:

```js
{
  time: UsersCountWithPrticularTime,
  ‘40’: 150,
  ‘50’: 50,
  ‘60’: 75,
  ‘40’: 90,
}
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do.  That function will be invoked separately for each document in the pipeline, and the return from the function will become the new value of the `newKey` field, `args` can only take values from the current document.  Depending on what you are trying to do, a`$group` stage may be helpful.

Comment: Agree with @Joe. If you can edit the question to describe what you want the $function to do then we could help advise on the overall pipeline. In general $function can often be avoided by using other stages an operators that are available within the aggregation framework

Comment: Also note that most stages in an  aggregation pipeline have a memory limit somewhere around 100MB, so even if you find a way to bring all of the documents together in a single array, 100k documents would mean you have a hard 1KB limit on each document.

Comment: thank you guys, yes I was approaching this problem with a really bad one. but finally able to solve it with $bucket!

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the best optimize solution by using $bucket
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).